# Does CComSafeArray MultiDimSetAt Make a Copy of the Referenced Element?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, visual-c++, atl

The [CComSafeArray::SetAt method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9thw32d7.aspx) provides a parameter to control whether the referenced variable is copied:

```
HRESULT SetAt(
LONG lIndex,
const T& t,
BOOL bCopy = TRUE
);
```

... but the [CComSafeArray::MultiDimSetAt method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wbystyc.aspx) does not offer the same parameter:

```
HRESULT MultiDimSetAt(
const LONG * alIndex,
const T& t 
);
```

Two questions:

1.) Is there a reason that this option is not offered in the MultiDim method?

2.) The docs don't specify if the referenced variable is copied. Is it copied implicitly?

(In my case I would like it *not* to be copied, since it is a temporary wrapper for a VARIANT type that could be 'Detach'd after setting it into the array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally MultiDimSetAt uses SafeArrayPutElement function. 
It means that BSTRs would be copied and objects would be AddRef'ed.